# Page responding very slow when i execute query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, pagespeed

This is long but i have to write

1.I have on website with  **100000 products**
database size of **7705.13 MB** and using sql server express

Now, Before we were load data into sessions so **100000 products** in one session and filter it according to requirement like i need only **30 at one page** so i will take it and others will load according to requirement but there was a performace issues so we moved to query and now we use similar functionality like this

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84211/pagination-through-sql-query

Now paging and sorting is good at performace
Real question i notice that page was loading at 30s before its reduce to 12s now but again its very long time to load so i decided to analyze it

So i execute my queries in sql it takes 00:00:00 seconds to execute but from c# when i debug it takes about **8seconds** or **10 seconds approx**  to load data into datatables so i thinks that the point to mark so any suggestions for this one? or there can be other circumstances? any help would be appritiated

```
public DataTable Load(string banner_type, int tag)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter("index_master", cn);
        dad.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition", banner_type);
        dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tag", tag);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cn.Open();
            dad.Fill(dset, "banner_master");
            return dset.Tables["banner_master"];
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dset.Dispose();
            dad.Dispose();
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I am using this method in my entire website to load. thanks in advance
***[Updated]***

**See i have shrinked my database once if that would be the case i don't know that is performace issue or not**

***My database product structure***
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyskC.jpg

**[Query]**

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.product_master.product_id,      dbo.product_master.product_name , dbo.product_master.recommended_pro5, dbo.product_master.discount_group_id, dbo.product_master.active,''sale'' AS price_type, dbo.product_master.up_date,dbo.category_master.category_id, dbo.shipping_rule_master.shipping_id from product_master inner join.......
```

Comment: DataAdapter/DataSet are really slow. Not THAT slow though, but I see no reason to use them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what should i use for that?

Comment: what are you bringing back?  E.g., are you storing product images in the database or are they file-based on the app server?  Can you post the structure of your product table?

Comment: No its file system @ps2goat and i am giving you my database structure wait

Comment: @ps2goat check updated

Comment: You gave us a link that mentioned paging, but I don't see where that is being done-- you don't have enough parameters to your `"index_master"`.  What exactly did you do with paging?

Comment: Paging is not the problem in paging i follow exact procedure the main problem is loading data to dataset it takes too much time in case of paging its working as i planned

Comment: General suggestion : make indexes on the columns that you are using to filter records. This will surely decrease the time to fetch records.

Comment: Ok @AshishCharan but incase of 4 table results?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Whichever column is after WHERE clause. Just make a index on them and check.

Comment: @AshishCharan can you tell me how? i have fourtables in one select query so now i want to apply index on it your suggestion is owsome i want to try

Comment: Could you please share the query?

Comment: @AshishCharan-- agreed that indexes are required, but that shouldn't be the issue if the same exact query is run in SSMS with no delay.

Comment: @AshishCharan check now

Comment: @dholakiyaankit what about your joins?

Comment: In SSMS you are already logged in, and then you run the query. While from code, you need to create connection and then execute the query, so it would take a little long from the code.

Comment: @ps2goat Have to put? that queries joins?

Comment: If you want answers...  How are you implementing paging?  Your code doesn't show any type of paging being used.

Comment: ya i am really stuck in this i don't know where's the problem

Comment: @ps2goat paging is not a problem i clearly says that because the page which i am analyzing have only 19 datas which is my default size and not need to do paging there